# Mounting tv using wall studs, cant drill more than ~1 inch

Tags: mounting, studs, mount

Hello so I am trying to mount my tv using a rosewill RHTB-16001 and trying to drive in the pilot holes to be able to screw in the lag bolts.
Following the manual using a 1/4 inch drill bit I drilled into what i believe to be the stud locations using a stud finder that seems shoddy, and attempting to find by measuring from corner.  I'm pretty sure i got them as the two locations are about 16 inches apart so I drill into it and get about 1-1.5 inches in when i hit a pretty solid surface.  It seems like the stud but if I flash a light on it it looks metallic.  It gives that metal look on the two separate stud locations I found.  Are these metal studs? if they are what are my options for mounting?  Pictures attached [image: stud]

Mount
[https://www.amazon.com/Rosewill-Monitors-800x400mm-Extension-RHTB-16001/dp/B01N8Q22VF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N8Q22VF)

Comment: Sheet rock is typically 3/8" or 1/2" thick.  If you are drilling a full inch before you hit something solid, I'd be surprised if it was a stud.  What's on the other side of this wall?

Comment: It's a wall that separate the living room and bedroom.  I may be overestimating the depth but it seemed to be an inch

Comment: Try sticking a small magnet into the hole you drilled and see if it is a metal stud. Age of home? Was it remodeled at some point? Metal studs are not all that common in residential construction as they cost more and are not as readily available. You could also try a 3" nail and try to sink it a little. If it bounces back, there is metal there. Now, there could be metal there, a cable plate, or a conduit, or even plumbing.

Comment: It's a condo built around 2008.  I used a magnet on the wall and dragged it across and no pull except lower down the stud line, at the same height for both studs.

Would it be safe to just go around these and use plastic anchors

Comment: I am new here. But i don't think you can hang a TV on Sheet Rock. If the instructions say Beam, then beam it is. You don't want your TV and wall to coming crashing down :o/